# Recommended Minimum Connections for dsPIC30F4011?

Tags: pic

In the dsPIC33FJ06GS101 ([pdf](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70318D.pdf)) manual a recommended minimum connection circuit it specified for that chip, pdf page 22. This includes decoupling capacitors, pull-up on MCLR and a few other things. For the dsPIC30F4011 ([pdf](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/70135C.pdf)) nothing is specified, not even in the Family Manual ([pdf](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70046D.pdf)).

Where can I find such recommendations? Decoupling capacitors are surely recommendable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to think for yourself on this one. Check out any reference designs of this or or similar family parts (such as the motor controller reference design). The ADC is important for mixed signal applications and you should refer to the reference in the datasheet for proper bypassing and decoupling (shown is a low performance application using the power supply as the ADC reference):

[image]

The /MCLR and programming connections should be similar to other family devices, but be sure to read the datasheet, the errata and the family reference manual carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This points me in the right way.